# delete a record from two tables in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to delete a "boat" from boat table and associated qualifications in another table using the following code:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_boat, tbl_qualifications 
WHERE tbl_boat.BT_ID = '$bt_id' AND tbl_boat.BT_ID = tbl_qualifications.BT_ID;
```

The problem is I'm receiving following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'WHERE tbl_boat.BT_ID = 113 AND tbl_boat.BT_ID = tbl_`' at line 2 .

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: may be you can get idea by this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339851/delete-rows-from-two-tables-in-one-query

Comment: You sure that this will work? `...WHERE tbl_boat.BT_ID = '$bt_id' AND tbl_boat.BT_ID = tbl_qualifications.BT_ID`: this would return the row only of `$bt_id` and `tbl_qualifications.BT_ID` were identical...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to perform two delete :

> -- DELETE all associations first ...
>   DELETE FROM tbl_qualifications WHERE BT_ID = '$bt_id';
>
> -- ... then delete the boat
>   DELETE FROM tbl_boat WHERE BT_ID = '$bt_id';

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try INNER JOIN.

```
DELETE FROM tbl_boat
INNER JOIN tbl_qualifications
WHERE tbl_boat.BT_ID = '$bt_id' AND tbl_boat.BT_ID = tbl_qualifications.BT_ID;
```

I haven't tested this, but I think this will work.

Comment: Maybe adding some more information will make this answer more useful. A [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) to mysql manual is good here, to explain how `DELETE` on multiple tables work

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell MySQL how the two tables are related:

```
DELETE tbl_boat, tbl_qualifications
FROM
    tbl_boat
    INNER JOIN tbl_qualifications USING (BT_ID)
WHERE
    tbl_boat.BT_ID = '$bt_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
DELETE tbl_boat, tbl_qualifications FROM tbl_boat, tbl_qualifications 
WHERE tbl_boat.BT_ID = '$bt_id' AND tbl_boat.BT_ID = tbl_qualifications.BT_ID;
```

btw take a look at [How to delete from multiple tables in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331992/how-to-delete-from-multiple-tables-in-mysql)

Comment: I tried it but this does not work. I receive the same error message.

Comment: It only works if I break it into two delete statements and only if delete from qualification executes before boat.

Answer (score 0):

This will definitely work:

```
DELETE a.*, b.*
FROM tbl_boat AS a
INNER JOIN tbl_qualifications AS b
    ON b.BT_ID = a.BT_ID
WHERE tbl_boat.BT_ID = '$bt_id';
```

Also, if the `BT_ID` is `INTEGER` type, then remove the quotation from around `$bt_id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
DELETE uploadfeat,postfeeds,postcomment FROM uploadfeat INNER JOIN postfeeds INNER JOIN postcomment
WHERE uploadfeat.id=postfeeds.postID AND uploadfeat.id=postcomment.postID AND uploadfeat.id=23
```