# delete a same data from multiple table in php

Tags: php

i have go through answer in here but i confuse... what is INNERJOIN or LEFTJOIN when delete a data. i have problem to delete same data in multiple table... this example 
i have

> Table user_information
>     contain user_id. primary key
>
> table registration 
>     contain user_id

this 2 table, i didn't create foreign key.. i want to delete the row that have specific user_id data.. i try to create this php code

```
<?php

include ('dbconnect.php');


$matric=$_GET['user_id'];


$sql="DELETE FROM user_information, registration WHERE user_id='$matric'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);


if($result){
header("location:../adminMuser.php");

}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?>

<?php

mysql_close();
?>
```

how to make a delete than when we delete specific user_id it can delete all data that have that user_id in both table. how to use the INNERJOIN or LEFTJOIN or what necessary i need to do... my php just show error

i also try to do this

```
$sql="DELETE user_id FROM user_information RIGHT JOIN registration ON user_information.user_id=registration.user_id WHERE user_id='$matric' ";
```

still it just show "ERROR"

Comment: possible duplicate of [delete a record from two tables in php/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407039/delete-a-record-from-two-tables-in-php-mysql)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting rows with MySQL LEFT JOIN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763206/deleting-rows-with-mysql-left-join)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options here:

1. Delete when a user_id is found in both the tables.

   ```
   DELETE a.*, b.* FROM user_information a
   INNER JOIN registration b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
   WHERE a.user_id='$matric';
   ```
2. Delete when a user_id is found in both tables along with NULL user_id in second table.

   ```
   DELETE a.*, b.* FROM user_information a
   LEFT OUTER JOIN registration b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
   WHERE a.user_id='$matric';
   ```
3. Delete when a user_id is found in both tables along with NULL user_id in first table.

   ```
   DELETE a.*, b.* FROM user_information a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN registration b ON a.user_id = b.user_id
   WHERE a.user_id='$matric';
   ```

Please see this sqlfiddle for clarity.

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!8/97cdd/1

Comment: Oh my bad!! I dint see the question correctly initially!

Comment: thanks.. this help... owh that the way to use join, what a,b means? is it variable?

Comment: a, b are alias names used for the tables mentioned in the query. Its just a way of assigning a short name to a table so that you don't have to use the entire big name again and again!!

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql1="DELETE FROM  registration WHERE user_id='$matric'";
$result=mysql_query($sql1); // delete the first registration table

$sql2="DELETE FROM user_information WHERE user_id='$matric'";
$result=mysql_query($sql2); // delete the user information table
```

Comment: how can i combine sql 1 and sql 2 to delete both at same time? what i need to change here $result=mysql_query($sql1,sql2); because previously it show problem...